# Error: thai word segmentation by use ICU4NET

Tags: c#, .net

- This is code thai word segmentation by use ICU4NET:

  ```
              using ICU4NET;
              using ICU4NETExtension;

              static void Main(string[] args)
              {
                   var sb = new StringBuilder();
                   var col = new List<string>();

                   using (BreakIterator bi = BreakIterator.CreateWordInstance(Locale.GetUS()))
                   {
                       bi.SetText(Content2);
                       int start = bi.First(), end = bi.Next();
                       while (end != BreakIterator.DONE)
                       {
                            col.Add(Content2.Substring(start, end - start));
                            start = end; end = bi.Next();
                       }
                   }
               }
  ```
- I write by use program Visual studio 2008
- but it error because "Could not load file or assembly 'ICU4NET, Version=1.0.3891.39017, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format". I do not know what it is.

Comment: Do you have the assemblies referenced in your project? And do you have the correct using statements? `using ICU4NET; using ICU4NETExtension;`

Answer (score 1):

[How to use ICU4NET](https://code.google.com/p/icu4net/)

```
Add references to ICU4NET.dll and ICU4NETExtension.dll.
Make sure that ICU4C's DLLs, including icudt42.dll, icuin42.dll, icuio42.dll, icule42.dll, iculx42.dll, icutu41.dll, and icuuc42.dll, are in the %PATH% or in the working directory of your exe program.
```